# Convert &amp; to &

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

**Scenario:**

In the table, the data is stored as `"Ernst &amp; Young"`, While performing ETL operation using SSIS, i need to convert `&amp;` to `&`. How can I do it?

**Update #1:**

Is there any transformation component to convert this? Personally I don't want to use script component transformation.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Derived Column** with expression `Replace(<your_column>,"&amp;","&")`.

However, I would opt against it. Besides `&amp;` you might have in your string `&lt;` etc. If this is the case and your string is HTTP-escaped, a simple Script transformation with single call to [System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_) would do the trick completely. In pure SSIS you will need to do a lot of consecutive **Derived Column** transforms.